# Using Phpcassa in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cassandra, phpcassa

Has anyone been able to use Phpcassa in a Yii application. I have tried adding the phpcassa folder into the components which I have added to the config for auto loading but its not recognizing the phpcassa classes and they are not getting autoloaded.

I have used the phpcassa code in a standalone php file and it all works well so I know everythng is in place, just that I cant load the phpcassa classes in Yii.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Dave

I managed to get the necessary classes loaded. This may not be the right way but it works for me.
I unloaded Yii autoload, added my classes and phpcassa autoloader like in the phpcassa examples and then registered the autoloaded again.

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); // Disable Yii autoloader
require_once(__DIR__.'/../extensions/lib/autoload.php');
use phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool;
use phpcassa\ColumnFamily;
use phpcassa\ColumnSlice;
use phpcassa\SystemManager;
use phpcassa\Schema\StrategyClass;
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
```

Thanks for the help Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Applications components directory is autoloaded automatically, so you shouldn't need to change your config.  I'm not familiar with phpcassa but things to check include:-

- Is the filename identical to the classname?
- Does phpcassa include sub-classes?  These won't be auto-loaded by default.

edit: Hi, try using Yii::registerAutoloader in your bootstrap.  With Zend, I use the code like this:-

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader',  'autoload'), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris,
I think you might be right about the sub classes. When using PHPCassa it has its own autoloader that it uses and I am not sure how this effects the Yii autoloading. 

Here is a sample of code from the Phpcassa example where it loads the phpcassa classes

require_once(__DIR__.'/../lib/autoload.php');
use phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool;